# What is the authenticity for this Du'a about Faith, Knowledge and Guidance?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith

It is narrated in the Musannaf of Ibn Abi Shaybah ([30364](https://shamela.ws/book/9944/34478#p1)) and in his Kitab al-Iman ([106](https://shamela.ws/book/7767/105)) that Abu Darda (rn) made this following Du'a:

> '*Ya Allah, I ask You for permanent faith (Iman), beneficial knowledge, and valuable guidance*' Mu'awiyah said: '[From this Du'a we understand that] Iman is not always perpetual, there is knowledge that is not beneficial and guidance that is not valubale.'

---

I would like to know the authenticity for this supplication since I can not find any classification for it?

Comment: If you can find the edition of musannaf ibn abi shaybah annotated by Shaykh Muhammad Awwamah (r), will clarify all the Hadith in it. It's 26 volumes in total!. And about the musnad ad daylami and Al hilyah, i am not familiar with those. Hope someone well versed in those works as well can provide you an answer, in Sha Allah.